# Combinatorics question - Round of 8 draw

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, factorial

"In the Champions League Round of 8 draw on some year, the clubs present are: Barcelona, Bayern, Benfica, Inter Milan, Liverpool, Man City, PSG and Real Madrid.

a) Of all the draws possible, in which ones we have Barcelona and Bayern facing each other?

b) Of all the draws possible, in which ones we have Inter Milan facing an English club?"

I know it looks simple, but i'm having some troubles.

edit: I know that the number of possible draws are $$\dfrac{8!}{2^{4}\times 4!} = \frac{8\times7\times6\times5\times4!}{2^{4}\times4!} = 7\times3\times5=105$$

Then, given that the draws that one determinated club will face another club are equal (there are no restrictions whatsoever), then the draws that pits barcelona and bayern against each other is 15?

It's $\dfrac{1}{7}$ of the possible draws all along? :O

for letter b) i'm still drawing a blank.

edit2: I just found this is the formula of the double factorial.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking in how many ways these events could happen in the quarterfinals or in the tournament?

Comment: Hint: How many possible draws in total do you think there are?  What proportion do you think have Barcelona playing Bayern rather than one of the other teams?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig for the quarterfinals only.

Comment: @Henry If I had to guess, it's $\frac{8!}{2^{4} \times 4!}$. Is this right?

Comment: There are indeed $\frac{1}{4!}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ possible draws.  Please add your attempt to your question and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Some ways of counting affect the number of draws: for example the draw determines which of two teams plays away first and home second (generally though a small advantage).  So instead of your $7\times 5\times 3 \times 1$ you get $14 \times 10 \times 6 \times 2$.  In fact the UEFA quarter-final draws include the consequential semi-final draws as part of it, which would increase the numbers further. So opinion as what the question asks comes into this part.   Easier to answer is  *"What proportion of draws do you think have Barcelona playing Bayern rather than one of the other teams?"*

Comment: @N.F.Taussig ok, thanks.

Comment: Can't resist - no such team as Inter Milan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solved the first problem correctly.

Suppose the teams are listed alphabetically.  Barcelona would then be the first team on the list.  There are seven ways to select an opponent for Barcelona.  That leaves six teams.  There are five ways to select an opponent for the first team remaining in the list.  That leaves four teams.  There are three ways to select an opponent for the  first team remaining in the list.  The remaining two teams must play each other.  Therefore, there are
$$7!! = 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 = 105$$
possible draws for the round of $8$.

If Barcelona plays Bayern, we have to arrange matches for the remaining six teams, which can be done in
$$5!! = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot = 15$$
ways, as you found.

If Inter Milan plays one of the two English clubs, there are two ways to select its opponent.  Once that opponent is selected, we have to arrange matches among the remaining six teams, which can be done in $5!!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$2 \cdot 5!! = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 = 30$$
possible draws for the round of $8$ in which Inter Milan plays an English club.

If you think in terms of symmetry, notice that $1/7$th of the possible draws have Barcelona playing Bayern in the round of $8$.  Similarly, $2/7$ of the possible draws have Inter Milan playing an English club in the round of $8$.